# Limiting documents pushed to array in group aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection `comments`. Each comment has an `authorId`.

I want to group the `comments` collection into 'threads' by the `authorId`, and attach the 5 most recent comments.

So far I have tried this:

```
db.comments.aggregate([{$group: { _id: "$authorId", recentComments: { $push: "$$ROOT"} }}])
```

But this attaches all comments. I then tried to add a limit like this:

```
db.comments.aggregate([{$group: { _id: "$authorId", recentComments: { $push: "$$ROOT"} }}, {$limit: 5}])
```

But this doesnt limit the number of documents, but instead the number of grouped documents.

Any ideas?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940862/which-nosql-system-to-get-n-rows-for-each-group-3-dimensional-nested-update/31946637#31946637

Answer (score 1):

Adding a project worked for me...

```
db.comments.aggregate([
  {$group: { _id: "$authorId", recentComments: { $push: "$$ROOT"} }},
  {$project: {_id: 1, title: 1, recentComments: {$slice: ['$recentComments', 0, 5]}}}])
```